# How do I get webpack working with electron using aurelia?

Tags: node.js, typescript, webpack, electron, aurelia

right now I'm just trying to add electron to the basic hello world app (well, I did tweak some options in the aurelia cli, but still it's just at hello world webpack+typescript).

my current attempt is to use [webpack-electron](https://webpack.electron.build), what I'm getting is a white screen of death. I can also get a black screen of death, if I exclude the renderer, it can't find any of the resource files in that case, it's looking for them at the wrong path.

here's my `src/main/app.ts`

```
import { app, BrowserWindow } from "electron";
import * as path from "path";

let mainWindow: Electron.BrowserWindow;

const isDevelopment = process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production';

function createWindowUrl(url) {
  const prefix = isDevelopment
    ? `http://localhost:${process.env.ELECTRON_WEBPACK_WDS_PORT}`
    : `file://${__dirname}`;

  return `${prefix}/${url}`;
}

function createWindow() {
  // Create the browser window.
  mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({
    height: 600,
    width: 800,
    webPreferences: {
      nodeIntegration: true,
    }
  });


  // and load the index.html of the app.
  mainWindow.loadURL(createWindowUrl('../index.html'));

  // Open the DevTools.
  mainWindow.webContents.openDevTools();

  // Emitted when the window is closed.
  mainWindow.on("closed", () => {
    // Dereference the window object, usually you would store windows
    // in an array if your app supports multi windows, this is the time
    // when you should delete the corresponding element.
    mainWindow = null;
  });
}

// This method will be called when Electron has finished
// initialization and is ready to create browser windows.
// Some APIs can only be used after this event occurs.
app.on("ready", createWindow);

// Quit when all windows are closed.
app.on("window-all-closed", () => {
  // On OS X it is common for applications and their menu bar
  // to stay active until the user quits explicitly with Cmd + Q
  if (process.platform !== "darwin") {
    app.quit();
  }
});

app.on("activate", () => {
  // On OS X it"s common to re-create a window in the app when the
  // dock icon is clicked and there are no other windows open.
  if (mainWindow === null) {
    createWindow();
  }
});

// In this file you can include the rest of your app"s specific main process
// code. You can also put them in separate files and require them here.
```

and my `src/renderer/main.ts` which I'm sure is wrong per https://medium.com/kendraio/using-angular-with-electron-webpack-b9763903823c

```
import {} from "../main"
```

I don't really care if I use `webpack-electron`, but how do I get aurelia working with electron in a way that also preserves the normal website/server code?

versions, but I doubt they matter

```
Calebs-MBP:warmaster calebcushing$ yarn list --depth=0 --pattern "^webpack|^aurelia|^electron"
yarn list v1.21.1
├─ aurelia-animator-css@1.0.4
├─ aurelia-binding@2.5.2
├─ aurelia-bootstrapper@2.3.3
├─ aurelia-cli@1.2.3
├─ aurelia-dependency-injection@1.5.2
├─ aurelia-event-aggregator@1.0.3
├─ aurelia-framework@1.3.1
├─ aurelia-history-browser@1.4.0
├─ aurelia-history@1.2.1
├─ aurelia-hot-module-reload@0.2.1
├─ aurelia-loader-default@1.2.1
├─ aurelia-loader-webpack@2.2.1
├─ aurelia-loader@1.0.2
├─ aurelia-logging-console@1.1.1
├─ aurelia-logging@1.5.2
├─ aurelia-metadata@1.0.6
├─ aurelia-pal-browser@1.8.1
├─ aurelia-pal@1.8.2
├─ aurelia-path@1.1.5
├─ aurelia-polyfills@1.3.4
├─ aurelia-route-recognizer@1.3.2
├─ aurelia-router@1.7.1
├─ aurelia-task-queue@1.3.3
├─ aurelia-templating-binding@1.5.3
├─ aurelia-templating-resources@1.13.0
├─ aurelia-templating-router@1.4.0
├─ aurelia-templating@1.10.3
├─ aurelia-testing@1.0.0
├─ aurelia-tools@2.0.0
├─ aurelia-webpack-plugin@3.0.0
├─ electron-builder@22.3.2
├─ electron-devtools-installer@2.2.4
├─ electron-publish@22.3.2
├─ electron-to-chromium@1.3.345
├─ electron-webpack-js@2.3.4
├─ electron-webpack@2.7.4
├─ electron@8.0.0
├─ webpack-bundle-analyzer@3.6.0
├─ webpack-cli@3.3.10
├─ webpack-dev-middleware@3.7.2
├─ webpack-dev-server@3.10.3
├─ webpack-log@2.0.0
├─ webpack-merge@4.2.2
├─ webpack-sources@1.4.3
└─ webpack@4.41.5
✨  Done in 1.03s.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

using [Capacitor](https://capacitor.ionicframework.com/docs/getting-started) for this is far easier, [just follow this document](https://capacitor.ionicframework.com/docs/electron).

Then add `electron-builder` as dev to the `electron` project added by capacitor. Add these scripts to package your app, and you're good to go.

```
{
  "scripts": {
    "pack": "electron-builder --dir",
    "dist": "electron-builder"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

So this is probably not a be-all end all but I got the hello world to display in electron, so here's what I did

TL;DR;
change the `webpack.config.js` `baseUrl` to be `''` (an empty string)

add these to `package.json` with your package manager (I'm not sure if `electron-builder` is required)

```
    "electron": "^8.0.0",
    "electron-builder": "^22.3.2",
    "electron-webpack": "^2.7.4",
...scripts
    "build:electron": "npm run build && electron-webpack app",
    "package:electron": "npm run build:electron && electron-builder",
    "start:electron": "npm run build:dev && electron-webpack dev",
...// electron webpack and builder configuration
  "electronWebpack": {
    "commonSourceDirectory": "dist",
    "staticSourceDirectory": "static",
    "title": true
  },
  "build": {
    "directories": {
      "buildResources": "dist",
      "output": "electron"
    },
    "files": [ // actually include the dist folder
      {
        "from": "dist",
        "to": "dist"
      }
    ]
  },
  "main": "main.js",
```

then add a `src/main/app.ts` and a `src/main/renderer.ts` (renderer will remain an empty file)

in `src/main/app.ts` add this code which is basically the electron typescript quickstart code with one change. The file loaded it just `../index.html`, `__dirname` will look in the wrong place.

```
import { app, BrowserWindow } from "electron";
import * as path from "path";
import { format as formatUrl } from 'url';


let mainWindow: Electron.BrowserWindow;

function createWindow() {
  // Create the browser window.
  mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({
    height: 600,
    width: 800,
  });
  const isDevelopment = process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production';

  // Open the DevTools.
  mainWindow.webContents.openDevTools();

  // and load the index.html of the app.
// this conditional is silly, but was the only way I figured out how to have it work in both dev and actually packaging the app
  if (isDevelopment) {
    mainWindow.loadFile(path.relative(__dirname, 'dist/index.html'))
  } else {
    mainWindow.loadURL(formatUrl({
      pathname: path.join(__dirname, 'dist/index.html'),
      protocol: 'file',
      slashes: true
    }));
  }

  // Emitted when the window is closed.
  mainWindow.on("closed", () => {
    // Dereference the window object, usually you would store windows
    // in an array if your app supports multi windows, this is the time
    // when you should delete the corresponding element.
    mainWindow = null;
  });
}

// This method will be called when Electron has finished
// initialization and is ready to create browser windows.
// Some APIs can only be used after this event occurs.
app.on("ready", createWindow);

// Quit when all windows are closed.
app.on("window-all-closed", () => {
  // On OS X it is common for applications and their menu bar
  // to stay active until the user quits explicitly with Cmd + Q
  if (process.platform !== "darwin") {
    app.quit();
  }
});

app.on("activate", () => {
  // On OS X it"s common to re-create a window in the app when the
  // dock icon is clicked and there are no other windows open.
  if (mainWindow === null) {
    createWindow();
  }
});

// In this file you can include the rest of your app"s specific main process
// code. You can also put them in separate files and require them here.
```

and then change `webpack.config.js` as previously stated and try `npm run start` and `npm run start:electron` and both should now run.